# How to create windows forms dialog with dynamic number of buttons?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to create a sort of a dialog box or something like a popup screen. I have this array of items and then I need to create a buttons for each of them on the dialogbox so that i could navigate with a button click.

Whats the best way to do it in C#? can someone guide me on this please

Comment: You can create a custom message box. This is a [A Custom Message Box](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17253/A-Custom-Message-Box)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms), then place `FlowLayoutPanel` on your form. Then add all controls to it at runtime.

```
foreach(var item in items)
{
   Button button = new Button();
   // setup button properties
   // subscribe to events
   flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(button);
}
```

[FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zah8ywcc.aspx) will arrange your controls automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that you Dialog or similar parent element is called sp and ar is the array of elements that you want to use to create the buttons:

```
for(YourObject obj : ar)
{
  System.Windows.Controls.Button newBtn = new Button();
  newBtn.Content = obj.YourProperty;
  newBtn.Name = "Button" + obj.YourProperty;
  sp.Children.Add(newBtn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was playing with some concepts and **one part** of it seem to be exactly example of creating dynamic dialog. You can add dynamic button creation to it, combine it and properly format it using table or flow layout panel

```
DialogResult result;
using (var popup = new Form())
{
    popup.Size = new Size(1000, 500);
    popup.Location = new Point(Convert.ToInt32(this.Parent.Width / 2) - 500, Convert.ToInt32(this.Parent.Height / 2) - 250);
    popup.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
    popup.MinimizeBox = false;
    popup.MaximizeBox = false;
    popup.Text = "My title";
    var lbl = new Label() { Dock = DockStyle.Top, Padding = new Padding(3), Height = 30 };
    lbl.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11f);
    lbl.Text = "Do you want to Continue?";

    // HERE you will add your dynamic button creation instead of  my hardcoded

    var btnYes = new Button { Text = "Yes", Location = new Point(700, 400) };
    btnYes.Click += (s, ea) => { ((Form)((Control)s).Parent).DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes; ((Form)((Control)s).Parent).Close(); };
    var btnNo = new Button { Text = "No", Location = new Point(900, 400) };
    btnNo.Click += (s, ea) => { ((Form)((Control)s).Parent).DialogResult = DialogResult.No; ((Form)((Control)s).Parent).Close(); };

    popup.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { lbl, btnYes, btnNo });
    result = popup.ShowDialog(this);

}
if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    // do this
}
else
{
   // do that
}
```

This was example of how to create dynamic dialog with dialog result output.